# Getting error after upgrade to RN 0.57 , with title backgroundColor

Tags: react-native

[image]

Maybe someone saw that error ? It occurs only in 0.57 version

Comment: Please provide the code .. may be you are using backgroundColor as variable and not as property

Comment: Welcome to`SO`, you should explain a little more. put some your codes and embed your picture.

Comment: All works on version 0.56 , just when I upgrade with react-native-git-upgrade this error occurs, my project is large, what code i should provide ?

Answer (score 2):

I found solution , in new RN 0.57 we couldn't set backgorundColor property to null, it must be undefined, that was a problem.